# What are the possible use cases of the OrientDb Live Query feature?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I apologise if the question is naive. I wanted to understand what could be a few possible use cases of the live query feature.

Let's say - My database state changes but it doesn't change every minute (or hour). If I execute a live query against my database/class/cluster, I'm not really expecting the callback to be called anytime soon. But, hey, I would still want to be notified when there's a state change.
My need with Orientdb is more on lines of ElasticSearch's percolator bundled with a publish-subscribe system.

Is live query meant to cater to such use cases too? Or is my understanding of live query very limited? What could be a few possible use cases for the live query feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not Live Queries will be appropriate for your use case depends on a few things.  There are several reason why live queries make sense.  A few questions to ask are:

1. How frequently does the data change?
2. How soon after the data changes do you need to know about it?
3. How many different groups of data (e.g. classes, clusters) do you need to deal with?
4. How many clients are connected to the server?

If the data does not change very often, or if you can wait a set period of time before an update, or you don't have many clients (hitting the DB directly), or if you only have one thing feeding the database, then you might want to just do polling.  There is a balance between holding a connection open that you send a message on very infrequently (live queries) and polling too often.

For example.  It's possible that you have an application server (tomcat, node, etc) and that your clients connect via web sockets.  Now lets say your app server makes one (or a few pooled) live query to the database.  Now lets say your database has an update.  It might just go from the database to the app server (e.g. node).  Node may now be responsible for fanning out that message across 100 web sockets (1 for each connected client).  In this case, the fact that node is connected to the database in a persistent way with a live query open, is not that big of a deal.

The question is.  If you have thousands of clients connected, do they all need an immediate update.  If so are you planning on having them polling at a short interval?  If so, you probably could benefit from a live query.  Lots of clients polling at a short interval will generate a lot of unnecessary traffic and queries.

Unfortunately at the end of the day, the answer is it depends.  You probably need to prototype and then instrument under load to see what your tradeoffs are.  But in principal, it is less about how frequently updates come, and more about how often you would have clients poll, and how many clients you have.  If the answer is "short intervals and a lot of clients"  Give live queries a try.